# multi column search in a table using jquery (Algorithm needed)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write a multi column search in a table. Due to some reason (support issue), I am unable to use datatable and table sorter plugin. I need your help in algorithmic part that how can I make multi column search. Please do not give me the link of already created plugins since I have changed table structure too much and I am unable to use those. I need something like this

datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

if I will get the hint for how its algo works, I will write the same function for me. I have written this code, but it is working on single column search, when I am searching in another column, it resets the search in multi column.

```
function searchonKeyPress(input_text_box)
{

  var query =   $.trim(input_text_box.val());
  query = query.replace(/ /gi, '|');
  if(query=='undefined')
  return false;
  var index_input = input_text_box.closest("th").index();
  index = $("#freeze-tableFreeze .GridviewScrollItem tr:eq("+index_input+") td").length;    
  $("#freeze-tableFreeze .GridviewScrollItem").each(function() {
  var tr_ident = $(this).attr('tr_ident');  
  var column_text = $(".GridviewScrollItem[tr_ident='"+tr_ident+"'] td:eq("+index_input+")").text();
  (column_text.search(new RegExp(query, "i")) < 0) ?        $(this).hide().removeClass('visible') : $(this).show().addClass('visible');

  });
  pagignation(1);
}
```

I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: stevanity: I want to do column search on html table like http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: @Ela:only algo will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you want to search in all the table: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/GZmuD/)

If you want to search **by column** try this :[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/gnypp/)

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>One<input type='text' class='search' /></th>
            <th>Two<input type='text' class='search' /></th>
            <th>Three<input type='text' class='search' /></th>
            <th>Four<input type='text' class='search' /></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    .........
```

JQuery:

```
$('.search').blur(function(){
$("td").removeClass('selected','');
var index=$(this).index('.search')+1;

    $('.search').each(function(index , val){

        var tag=$(val).val();
       if(tag!='') $("tr td:contains("+tag+")").addClass('selected');

    });

});
```

Comment: this is for search using single textbox in whole tr. I need multiple input each one for saperate td in tr.

Comment: this search for td , not for tr , search for hello in this example http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/QwVZv/

Comment: but, if there will be separate textboxs for each column, then your code will not work. as in first textbox you searched for one and in second textbox you searched for two. Now row containing one and two should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution here would be to select all td's in your table and filter them using jQuery [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector with the search phrase and highlight the rows / columns.

Take a look into [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RgTgM/) simple example. This selects all the cells with keyword 'one'.

```
$('td:contains(one)').css('color', 'red');
```

**Update :**

New [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/RgTgM/1/) with search box code.

Comment: Yes this would probably do it. But you can also implement server side search. Especially if your table is too big it can get pretty slow.

Comment: @stevanity True. This approach will be slow if the table data set is too large. In that case i would go with your suggestion for server side search.

Comment: @stevanity, I know but we are working on something that is more important on client side.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering you can use JQuery and manually iterate through the html markup to show/hide certain rows dependent on the filter criteria...

I build a small example of how to achieve this. Because you didn't provide any code, you'll have to adopt it

http://jsfiddle.net/Elak/FxBhQ/

The JQuery part is not overly complex, of cause you have to extend it to what ever functionality you want to have...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".searchBox").change(function () {
        var search = $(this).val();
        $(".column").each(function () {

            if ($(this).text().indexOf(search)) {
                $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```